# How to make verification process in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have powershell script. It has a lot of process such are get content, copy file, rename extension file, remove file, append text. 
I want to make verification for each process, so I will continue to the next process once I got correct result. For the example, for checking file, I use Test-Path. Is anyone give me idea, which verification is better to use in PowerShell?

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: From the term "verification" you mean "debugging"?

Comment: What you are asking for is a very common thing. It's really a PowerShell 101 thing. If you know what the result show be, then you are looking at using If/Then and or Try/Catch code blocks for the results you expect and want to take action on, Then there are several other options like parameter validation, etc, all of which is well documented on the MS docs site, TechNet, MSDN, and even videos on the MS Tech Community and Youtube. Just search for 'PowerShell validation'. You have a lot going on in your script so, this is not a simple one-liner / on function type of thing.

Comment: The suggested answers all sound like it'll do what you're asking, pretty basic really.  On the off-chance you're looking for human verification to continue through a script than you can prompt the user with a question to continue on the screen with a Write-Host "Continue? (Y/N) and then $response = Read-Host and set something to happen for either a Y or N answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `-WhatIf` parameter to debug any cmdlet. Also you can handle any errors and exceptions using `Try..Catch` block.
E.G

```
Try  {
  Get-Content "C:\foo.txt" -ErrorAction Stop
}
Catch {
  # The statements put here will be executed if any error was caught in try block
}
```

You can catch specific error using:

```
Try  {
  Get-Content "C:\foo.txt" -ErrorAction Stop
}
Catch [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException] {
  # The statements put here will be executed if file not found
  # Any exception can be placed in the [] braces
  # ErrorAction Common parameter is used to pass the errors to catch block and halt script on error
  # You can remove that if you don't want to halt script on error
}
```